# Looking for extensive world-building software

Tags: windows, 3d, game-development

I'm looking for a full-featured application for making entire sphere-like worlds.  Bonus points if it can also handle some of the physics for how two planetary bodies very near each other would interact.  I have Fractal Terrains 3, which is nice to get the basic geography of a single planet, but it does not have the abilities to populate said planet with plants and/or animals, export in a file type easily usable by other applications, nor can it simulate what would happen if I put two worlds very close to each other.  I understand that finding a single application that can do all of this is unlikely, but if it could at least do a lot of the above it would be nice.

Comment: You are aware of [WorldBuilding.se], which has also [posts about software](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+software)? Not that your question is off-topic here, but maybe there are already lots of suggestions over there.

Comment: And I remember seeing a series of posts on **a** SE site (don't remember with ones) about creating seas, land areas, coastlines etc. I cannot refind them, maybe you can with [searches like these](https://www.google.com/search?q=constructing+coastline+site%3Astackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Blender](http://www.blender.org).

Its a 3d graphics editor and can edit animate render export etc. with a built in game maker you can achieve what you want.

The Sculpt tool might help you to shape the geography of your planet. And you can download some characters from here so you don't have to make any >> [Animals](http://www.blendswap.com/terms/category/animals) [Animals 2](http://www.blender-models.com/model-downloads/animals/)

And the [Random World](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/79847)

Comment: I don't think Blender has the ability to process the necessary physics, though, which was that last item I needed.  I know that Blender can read scripts, thus be able to populate a planet after fiddling with a custom script designed for it, but the physics piece is still needed.

Comment: blender comes with elegant physics engine give it a try , and what type of `physics` animations are you talking of? even those that are not available can be programmed.

Comment: Imagine two earth-like, separated by only a hundred miles or so, kept apart be some alien structure attached to both planets.  Center of their orbit is right in the middle of them.  I want to model what the oceans would do and, if possible, rudimentary simulations on the modified weather patterns.